# C# - Correct way to check for nullable DateTime in if statement

Tags: c#

I have the following <del>code</del> method, which is designed to check if a user is blocked temporarily after invalidating their maximum attempts (say, 10) to login in a two hour period.

```
public MyError ValidationMethod(MyObject myObject) {
    int maxMaximumAttempts = 10;

    if (myObject.Attempts >= maximumAttempts && myObject.LastAttempt.Value.AddHours(2)) < DateTime.Now)
        return new MyError();

    return null;
}
```

Both of the DateTime fields, "Attempts" and "LastAttempt" are nullable, what is the proper way to format this if statement to ensure I don't get null reference exceptions?

Null for either of the fields, should be the same result as if the if statement returned false, i.e. they haven't tried to login before. I will then return null from the method itself which symbolises, no error was found with the input.

I thought the fields being null would make the whole statement false but instead I get a null reference exception, can anyone explain why please?

**Edit:** I have added the full method to make the context clearer.

Comment: What do you want to happen if either value *is* null?

Comment: Do the opposite `myObject.LastAttempt < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2)`. This will fail if `LastAttempt` is null.  You'll have to decide what to do if. `LastAttempt` is actually null though

Comment: Null in this case would mean they hadn't failed to login before, so the same result as if the code returned false. This code sits in a validation method so I would just return null if the check was false.

Comment: Use `myObject.LastAttempt < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2)` then

Comment: Instead of using nullable type, use plain DateTime but make use of DateTime.Max or DateTime.Min values for uninitialized cases. Then you won't need to worry about null.

Comment: @PhazorP I use a nullable type as for these fields, for compatibility with a database.They will remain as nullable types, so I would like to get that working.

Answer (score 2):

The nullable `DateTime` object has a property called `HasValue`, so you could write:

```cs
if (myObject.Attempts.HasValue && myObject.Attempts.Value >= maximumAttempts && myObject.LastAttempt.HasValue && myObject.LastAttempt.Value.AddHours(2) < DateTime.Now)
    return new myError();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can this code:

```
if (myObject != null && myObject.LastAttempt != null)
  if (myObject.Attempts >= maximumAttempts && myObject.LastAttempt.Value.AddHours(2) < DateTime.Now)
     return new myError();
```

or:

```
try
{
  if (myObject.Attempts >= maximumAttempts && myObject.LastAttempt.Value.AddHours(2) < DateTime.Now)
     return new myError();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   return new myError(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with nullables, use DateTime.MaxTime as not yet set value.
and for Attempts use 0 as not yet set value

```
 public class myType {
    // initialize myObject.LastAttempt = DateTime.MaxTime
    DateTime LastAttempt = DateTime.Max;
    int Attempts = 0;

/*
.... rest of the class
*/

}

public MyError ValidationMethod(MyObject myObject) {
    int maxMaximumAttempts = 5;

    if (myObject.Attempts >= maximumAttempts && myObject.LastAttempt != DateTime.Max && myObject.LastAttempt.AddHours(2)) < DateTime.Now)
        return new MyError();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I need to use a nullable type for compatibility with a database. Otherwise this is an excellent answer.

Comment: You could map between DB nulls to these application constants during serializarion and deserialization. If you can't, then you need to check for null with == nul, or check for not null with HasValue() methods. Or to make it more compact code you can combine null checks and Value property method calls with ?.Value operator. You need to be careful though. ?. won't apply to all cases, here it would not apply probably since result assignment is not to a nullable type.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would move these checks to the class which holds `Attempts` and `LastAttempt` fields (or at least created an extension for this class) - check [Tell Don't Ask Principle](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)

```
public class MyObject 
{
     public bool IsBlockedOn(DateTime time)
     {
        if (!Attempts.HasValue || !LastAttempt.HasValue)
            return false;

        var hasTooManyAttempts = MaximumAttempts <= Attempts.Value;
        var timeoutPassed = Timeout < (time - LastAttempt.Value);
        return hasTooManyAttempts && !timeoutPassed;
     }

     private TimeSpan Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
     private int MaximumAttempts = 10;
     // other properties
}
```

Your if statement:

```
if (myObject.IsBlockedOn(DateTime.Now))
   return new MyError();
```

The good part - this logic is now unit-testable because you can execute it with different time arguments.
Also, consider making Attempts non-nullable and initialize it with 0.